# EF Inheritance With Boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Say I have a `Tweet` class and `LongTweet` class which inherits from `Tweet`. In EF, they'd be modeled as one table, where I'll have a `Discriminator` column which will say either `Tweet` or `LongTweet`.

But say I want, instead of the `Discriminator` column to have `IsLongTweet` column which would be a bool value that is either going to be true if `LongTweet` is the instance or false if `Tweet` is the instance. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide any code you have so far? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with as much relevant information and any minimal code related to your question.

Comment: Do you want me to fill Tweet/LongTweet with some random properties in order to become more "relevant"? I think my question was pretty clear....

Comment: It would help for anyone searching for something similar, as well as provide some visual context to the question. If you could, yes, just provide a simplified example of your code to go along with the question.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here [Inheritance with EF Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

You should try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tweet>()
    .Map<Tweet>(m => m.Requires("IsLongTweet").HasValue(false))
    .Map<LongTweet>(m => m.Requires("IsLongTweet").HasValue(true));
```